# Adjust UITableView to allow for keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uikeyboard

What is the magical incantation for adjusting a `UITableView`'s height when the keyboard is shown on-screen FOR ALL DEVICES?  In the keyboardDidShow notification, I'm doing

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
```

where the bottom constraint of my table view is `Align Bottom to: Safe Area`.

This works perfectly on all iPhone 5|6|7|8-type devices, but NOT on iPhone X* devices; the adjustment is not of a sufficient amount so as to move the bottom of the table up to meet the top of the keyboard.  It's like ~58 pixels short.

Surely there must be some way to get this to work universally, eh?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because iphones except iPhone X have no bottom safe area . 
Try removing the view.safeAreaInsets.bottom.